# "GetOptionsFromString" is not exported by the Getopt::Long module

Tags: perl

I am trying to use [GetOptionsFromString](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-string) function and facing the following error:

> "GetOptionsFromString" is not exported by the Getopt::Long module

In the program I have the following lines added:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptionsFromString); 
use Getopt::Long;
```

I tried `perl -MGetopt::Long -e 'print $Getopt::Long::VERSION, "\n"'` and it prints 2.35.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 5):

That was added in version 2.36.  (The current version is 2.48.)

You will need to update [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) from CPAN.